# How do I automatically disable my third monitor when I turn it off - Windows 11

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-11, tv, displayport

I have three display outputs from my video card: monitor 1 (DisplayPort), monitor 2 (DisplayPort), and a TV (HDMI).

If the TV is turned off, and I move my mouse off to the right of the 2nd screen, it disappears and gets lost in the TV's view, even though the TV is turned off.

When I turn off my second monitor, that monitor is completely disabled and I cannot move my mouse onto that display at all.

I want to replicate this same behavior on my TV so that when I turn the TV off, I cannot interact with that display at all until it is turned back on.

Is there a way to make Windows 11 do this automatically?

Comment: Can you not just move your mouse onto the active display?

Comment: That's the issue. When the TV is turned off, I don't want my mouse or any windows to be able to move onto that display. I only want the displays which are turned on to be able to be interacted with.